# comparing array indexes or multi-dimentional array rows php

Tags: php, arrays

**I have 2 arrays to compare their indexes, how can i compare them by checking the empty indexes of first array and if so, then change the value of second array of same index.**

---

> it can be solved as 2D array by comparing the rows indexes.

---

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '10' (length=6)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => string '11' (length=3)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
array (size=5)
  0 => string '1' (length=4)
  1 => string '2' (length=11)
  2 => string '3' (length=11)
  3 => string '4' (length=11)
  4 => string '5' (length=10)
```

For instance, index 0 of first array is empty, so index 0 of second array incremented by 1. and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <?php
      $a=array('',10,11,'');
      $b=array(1,2,3,4,5);

      foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        if($v==''){

         $b[$k]=++$b[$k] ;
        }

        }

      print_r($b);

    ?>
```

**output**

Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 5 [4] => 5 )